# If I unzip a password-protected zip file, will the person I downloaded it from be notified in anyway?

Tags: zip

If I access a password protected zip file, that i've downloaded through tor, and then opened the zip file, is there any way the person who posted the zip file would be able to find out that I've opened it?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you open some executable within it or open it with archivator with known vulnerabilities, there is almost no way he can know. You can always airgap it by using VM's or literally disconnecting PC from any network.

Comment: Open source software can have vulnerabilities too.

Comment: Less likely though, due to constant code review cycles. At least with open source, vulnerabilities get disclosed and patched faster.

Comment: @Anodeman That depends on the open source tool. Unar v0.01 hasn't been updated for years and contains multiple vulnerabilities (mostly DoS though), and yet is widely used as an open source alternative to unrar.

Comment: @forest. Agree with that. So you still need to be on a lookout. Open souce is not panacea against vulnerabilities. But still amongst most secure, there is more open source tools, then proprietary. That's just in my experience.